# Android Basic Coding Try Catch Show Toast not working?

Tags: android, image, debugging, error-handling, try-catch

I'm building a real simple Android app and a lot is going wrong.

I can't even get a decent Try Catch Everything running. And since the machine I got is hugely underpowered I'm testing directly on my android device but that's not really working.

The application seems to crash after doing a basic action even using a generic try catch. What am I doing wrong here.

**Why is the try catch not catching anything?**

This is my Main.xml (a textview and another control are snipped out)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
        />
```

This is my simple code (and the Image isn't even showing)

```
public void onButtonClicked(View v) {
    try {
        String strFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/somefile.jpg";
        if (strFilePath.length() > 0) {

            File file = new File(strFilePath);

            if (file.exists()) {
                ShowToast(strFilePath + "Bestaat");

                ImageButton image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib);
                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strFilePath);
                image.setImageBitmap(bMap);

                ShowToast( "Done");
            } else {
                ShowToast(strFilePath + "Bestaat NIET");
            }
        } else {
            ShowToast(strFilePath + "strFilePath.length() =0");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        HandleError(e);
    }
}
```

**Solution**

The files where over 3Mb in size. The ImageButton won't show pictures that 'big' and simply do nothing.
The application probably threw some random out of memory exceptions loading the images taking down the entire app.

Reading a logcat was enough to debug this 'problem'

Some code that does work (kindly borrowed from other SO questions)

```
    ImageButton image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib);

    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strFilePath);
    Bitmap bSized = getResizedBitmap(bMap,150,150);
    image.setImageBitmap(bSized);
```

And

```
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth)                     
    {
      int width = bm.getWidth();
      int height = bm.getHeight();
      float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
      float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

      // create a matrix for the manipulation
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

      // resize the bit map
      matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

      // recreate the new Bitmap
      Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
      return resizedBitmap;

}
```

Comment: *"The application seems to crash"* - how? Doesn't respond anymore? Shows a "Force Close" dialog? Any other error message?

Comment: Get rid of the Try Catch block that way you wil see the real error in your LogCat!

Comment: Either you don't have an `ImageButton` with that id, or the image you are trying to load is to big to fit in the reduced application memory.

Comment: I Just get an Application has stopped - OK - option.

Comment: In this case you should have a stacktrace in the logcat - please post that.

Comment: @K-ballo right on track. It was the 'huge' image size. Unbelievable that a 'modern' environment would simply do nothing instead of some real error handling/notification. Not showing the image is really bad behavior in my book.

Comment: @CodingBarfield: That's up to you, you told the compiler you would handle the OutOfMemory or similar exception yet you didn't.

Comment: It never triggered any exception loading the image the first time couple of times. It simply never showed it. After clicking the button a couple of times offcourse is throw an OOM Exception. I had some catch code to write log info to a file, that never worked and neither did my Toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you don't have an `ImageButton` with that id, or the image you are trying to load is to big to fit in the reduced application memory.

Comment: According to the logcat the image was imply to big to show on an ImageButton and the default behaviour is to do and show nothing. After loading it a couple more times the app crashed with an OutOfMemoryException giving me no change to trigger any backup scenario since everything costs some memory.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I would expect `decodeFile` to at least return `null` if it fails to load something.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code snippets..

First of all, the ImageButton will not show the android:text part because that attribute belongs to Button..

With just the LinearLayout and the ImageButton in main.xml in the res/layout folder and this code it works fine:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void onButtonClicked(View v) {
    try {
        String strFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/somefile.png";
        if (strFilePath.length() > 0) {

            File file = new File(strFilePath);

            if (file.exists()) {
                //ShowToast(strFilePath + "Bestaat");

                ImageButton image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib);
                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strFilePath);
                image.setImageBitmap(bMap);

                //ShowToast( "Done");
            } else {
                //ShowToast(strFilePath + "Bestaat NIET");
            }
        } else {
            //ShowToast(strFilePath + "strFilePath.length() =0");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //HandleError(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

So either the file is to big as K-Ballo suggested or something is wrong with your ShowToast or HandleError methods.

Comment: Can you test it using a jpg file sized around 3Mb? What does it do on your device?

Comment: It crashed with:         Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:284)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:309)
        at com.example.Main.onButtonClicked(Main.java:35)